# How to set default value in Combobox using LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-combobox, default-value

```javascrript
    @wire(retrieveFields)
        listViewResults;
        get listViews(){           
            if (!this.listViewResults?.data){
                return [];
              }  
        let tempListViews = [];
        for(var listnameValue in this.listViewResults.data) {
            let lv = this.listViewResults.data[listnameValue];
            tempListViews.push({label: lv.Name, value: lv.Id});
        }
        
        console.log('Test02',tempListViews);
        //not sure what this is... prob should be another getter and use the zero index?
        //this.listviewId = this.listViewsNames[].value;
        return tempListViews;
        }

        get listViewId(){
        return this.listViews[0].value;
        }

    saveMethod() {
        this.handleIsLoading(true);
        const fields = {};

        fields[Name_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
        fields[User_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.userId; 
        const recordInput = {
        apiName: LISTVIEW_OBJECT.objectApiName,
        fields: fields
        };
        createRecord(recordInput)
        
            .then(record => {
                
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'la liste view a été bien créee',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
                //refreshApex(this.listViewsNames);
             //   this.listviewId = this.listViewsNames[0].value;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            }).finally(()=>{
                refreshApex(this.listViewResults);
                this.handleIsLoading(false);
            }); 
            this.closeModal();
    }
```

Html :

```html
<lightning-combobox
    name="fieldInfo"
    label="REQUETE"
    value={listViewId}
    placeholder="Selectionner une liste view "
    options={listViews}
    onchange={handleChange} >
</lightning-combobox>
```

Apex :

```apex
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List_View__c[] getUserListViews(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM List_View__c WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId() ORDER BY Name ASC];
}
```

I want to set the variable **listViewId** with the new created record from the method *createRecord*.
I believe that I need to change this method
`get listViewId(){ return this.listViews[0].value; }`
in order to get last created value, but i'm blocked.

Comment: Could you please edit the question adding the wired apex method?

Comment: @RubenDG done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance parameter to store the id of the created record (i.e. `latestListViewId`), which will be setted in `refreshApex().then()` to be sure it holds a valid value for the picklist, because if set it before the end of `refreshApex` you'll provide an invalid id to your combobox:

```js
latestListViewId;

saveMethod() {
    this.handleIsLoading(true);
    const fields = {};

    fields[Name_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
    fields[User_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.userId; 
    const recordInput = {
        apiName: LISTVIEW_OBJECT.objectApiName,
        fields: fields
    };
    let newRecordId;
    createRecord(recordInput)
        .then((record) => {
            newRecordId = record.id;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'la liste view a été bien créee',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            return refreshApex(this.listViewResults);
        })
        .then(() => { // this runs once refreshApex ends
            this.latestListViewId = newRecordId;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(()=>{
            this.handleIsLoading(false);
            this.closeModal();
        });
}
```

Finally you have to modify the getter for `listViewId` in order to return it if setted:

```js
get listViewId(){
    return this.latestListViewId || this.listViews[0].value;
}
```

Of course if showing the records ordered by their name is not mandatory, it's fastest just modify the apex method ordering the SOQL by `CreatedDate DESC`

Comment: where did you declared this variable **latestListViewId** ?

Comment: @Fabien it's a class property, so outside every method. You could declare it the line after the class declaration

Comment: i think it's not necessary to declare it , as it work when i do : **get listViewId(){
    return this.newRecordId** but i have another issue is that page doesn't work when i loading it , i should click on any buton first so it will load don't know why

Comment: @Fabien I edited the answer explaining where declare `latestListViewId` and why it should be setted after the refreshApex. Try it as-is and let me know if there is any issue, or if you modify the code before testing it please update the question reflecting it.

Comment: works well , i'm blocked on how to delete selected record in dropdown

Comment: @Fabien could you please elaborate? In the shared code there is no logic for deletion. How is related to this question? If the records are not the one retrieved via that apex method, please share also how do you get them.  Probably it's worth submitting a new question to overcome the comments' limitation

Comment: can we chat in private?

Comment: @Fabien I'll be offline until this evening. If you're going to open a new question please don't state just "how to delete selected record", but tell us how data is retrieved (i.e. an apex method return these records, in js I handle them to create an option list), what the user does (i.e. the user select an option, input some field then create a new record), when the delete should happen (i.e. once the record has been created I would like to delete the record XYZ or to hide the previous selected option), if there is any constraints and what you tried.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make a value as default value in combobox , i have created checkbox field and my idea was when user click on "Button" the checkbox pass to true but i didn't find solution on how to make only the checkbox related to the selected value as true and others to false .. have you any idea? forget the delete function

Comment: @Fabien if you have multiple checkbox and each one should be related to a specific value of a combobox, you need a map that holds this relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this in renderedCallback:

```
renderedCallback()
  const combobox = this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox');
  if(this.listViewResults.data && this.listViewResults.data.length && !combobox.value) {
    combobox.value = this.listValueResults[0].Id;
  }
}
```

You can add additional logic as you desire, but this should get you started.

Comment: but in this case you will always get the value with index 0 .

Comment: @Fabien again, this is only a hypothetical example. The point is, wait until the data is loaded, then set the desired value. Note that a render cycle only happens when there's "dirty" value. I'm on my phone, so I wasn't able to write a ton of code.

Comment: It will always be zero... UNLESS the user picks something else. There's not really any other way for the component to determine which value it should be unless you've stored it somewhere. This is how I've done it in the other related question.

Comment: it's been aa while that i'm blocked from posting new questions .. should i wait a decade?